# Google Site Map Generator Failed to open database

Tags: generator, sitemap

I am using google-sitemap-generator, every thing appears to be fine. But getting following error message in log file. This is resulting in failure to generate XML file.

> Failed to open
>   [/usr/local/google-sitemap-generator/cache//mysite.com__0/data_base]
>   to read.

It appears that,

> /cache//mysite.com__0/

some value is missing after cache/. Any hint would be great.

below is complete log file.

> 2013-09-24T07:09:56Z: Start to generate [Web Sitemap] for site
>   [mysite.com,:0]. 2013-09-24T07:09:56Z: No new record to update
>   news data. 2013-09-24T07:09:56Z: Failed to open
>   [/usr/local/google-sitemap-generator/cache//mysite.com__0/data_base]
>   to read. 2013-09-24T07:09:56Z: mysite.com,:0: record can't be
>   merged. 2013-09-24T07:09:56Z: Failed to update database.
>   2013-09-24T07:09:56Z: Failed to generate [Web Sitemap] for site
>   [mysite.com,:0]. 2013-09-24T07:17:40Z: Next service scheduling
>   time in [136]S. 2013-09-24T07:17:40Z: Save memory data for
>   [mysite.com,:0] successfully. 2013-09-24T07:19:56Z: Next
>   service scheduling time in [464]S. 2013-09-24T07:19:56Z: Start to
>   generate [Web Sitemap] for site [mysite.com,:0].
>   2013-09-24T07:19:56Z: No new record to update news data.
>   2013-09-24T07:19:56Z: Failed to open
>   [/usr/local/google-sitemap-generator/cache//mysite.com__0/data_base]
>   to read. 2013-09-24T07:19:56Z: mysite.com,:0: record can't be
>   merged. 2013-09-24T07:19:56Z: Failed to update database.
>   2013-09-24T07:19:56Z: Failed to generate [Web Sitemap] for site
>   [mysite.com,:0]. ~

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem like most people do with this tool. I got it to work by modifying 
"/usr/local/google-sitemap-generator/conf/sitesettings.xml" file.

What I did was remove "SiteSetting" node for 443 version of my_site.com, restarted the service and apache. And it started working, well, at least it was able to generate a sitemap for port 80.

Now I can see it restored the sitesettings.xml file but for some magical reason it won't report any errors anymore.

If you got it figured out then hopefully it will a useful info for someone else since many people seem to hit this problem. I spent whole yesterday evening trying to solve it with no success. Eventually I had to reinstall it and modify the xml file.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, I was using this tool last year and quit using this and wrote own tool to generate xml site map. It works like charm for me. My suggestion is, this tool is crap and heavy. Just write your own script( php in my case) and schedule a cron job.